# the sum does not match use sql query on MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to ask, I want to do the total time used using the sql:

```
  SELECT ea.NIK,
         LEFT(time(SUM(IF(TIMEDIFF(ea.timeIn,ts.tIn)<'00:00:00','',TIMEDIFF(ea.timeIn,ts.tIn)))),8) AS timeLate
  FROM EmployeeAttLog ea,
       transaksiChangeShift cs,
       mstTimeShift ts,
       mstGroupShift gs
  WHERE ea.NIK = cs.NIK
    AND cs.idGroupShift = gs.idGroupShift
    AND gs.idShift = ts.idShift
    AND ea.NIK = '01210456'
    AND WEEKDAY(ea.date) = gs.Idx
```

but **the results given don't match after I matched with ms. excel**

**data is :**

| NIK | TimeLate |
| --- | --- |
| 01210456 | 09:04:36 |
| 01210456 | 00:08:05 |
| 01210456 | 00:00:00 |
| 01210456 | 00:21:31 |
| 01210456 | 08:48:44 |
| 01210456 | 00:00:00 |
| 01210456 | 09:15:14 |
| 01210456 | 00:24:01 |
| Total | ..... |

the result in sql is **'27:21:31'**
the correct answer is '**28:02:11'**

the following data
*data on db and result :*
[image]

*cross check with ms excel :*
[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh: I've never used it, can give an example for a case like the one above. thank

Comment: `FROM EmployeeAttLog ea JOIN transaksiChangeShift cs ON ea.NIK = cs.NIK JOIN <next table> ON ... JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ea.NIK = '01210456'`

Comment: @jarlh :Thanks for the advice, for the first time I did my db using the sql tiper, but since time goes by I use the sql that I currently use, because it catches up to speed when collecting / processing data

Comment: The results look the same to me, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff :the result my sql is "27:21:31"